# PHP - compare two diffrent type variable bug or issue

Tags: php

There is two different type of variables. but while comparing both variable using == operator it returns weired output. Is this bug or some other issue? I am surprised.
Here is code,

```
$a=1000;
$b='1000square';
if($a==$b){
    echo "a equal b";
}else{
    echo "a not equal b";
}
```

It outputs : a equal b. 
But expected : a not equal b.

Can anyone explain?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Congratulations, you have posted some code, care to share your output?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `==` and `===` in PHP. See the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

What happens in the statement `$a==$b` is that PHP needs to decide how to compare `$a` and `$b`. Since at least one operand (`$a`) is a number, PHP uses numerical comparison instead of string comparison. Therefore `$b` is converted to a number. In PHP, the string `'1000square'` is converted to the number 1000. This is why your code shows that `$a==$b` is true.

However, `$a===$b` is false, since `===` compares the type as well. This might be the operator you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`$b` gets typecast to a number so it can be [compared](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to `$a`, therefore the resulting `$b` (the number `1000`) will be equal to `$a`. You should use `===` instead of `==` if you want to find out if the two variables are *identical*, not just *equal*. `===` doesn't typecast, and only returns `true` if both variables are of the same type *and* equal.